# Why ubuntu is taking so long to boot? I have used boot chart which shows a boot time of 90 seconds

Tags: ubuntu, boot

My system slowed down and now its taking about 90 seconds to boot according to boot chart. After starting also it is taking a lot to time to gain a good speed for tasks to launch.

Here is the output log for bootchart for my system (click on it for larger view):

[image: Here is the output log for bootchart for my system]

Comment: 90 seconds seems like a relatively long time but not insanely long.  You need to provide specifics about your system, what loads at startup, etc. for anybody to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issue that may apply:

- A failing disk may take longer to respond.  If your disks are SMART capable check their status.
- Insufficient memory will cause increased paging/swap activity which will load the disk(s) and slow response time.
- Insufficient swap space can also cause slow performance during startup.  (There is little if any penalty to paging out initialization code/data once initialization is complete.)
- If you have sufficient memory, (or even if not) it helps to have /tmp mounted as a `tmpfs` file system.  This resides in swap and will require more swap space.
- If your CPU is capable of multiple speeds, then it may not be increasing speed as required.  (You may also want to check CPU temparature if you can get it.)